# How to display the post using a shortcode in WordPress?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, shortcode

I am trying to display all the post on my page but it's not displaying. I am using the below code and I added the shortcode gridPost on my page. I am getting the only UL LI but not getting the title name.

```
function getAllPost(){
    $postData=[];
    $wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'project', 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>-1));
 if ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) :
    $postData[]='<ul>';
  while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post();
        $postData[]='<li><a href="'.the_permalink().'">'.the_title().'</a></li>';
    endwhile;
    $postData[]='</ul>';
    wp_reset_postdata();
 
  else : 
    $postData[] ='<p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>';
  endif;
        $postData = implode( '', $postData );
    return $postData;
}
add_shortcode( 'gridPost', 'getAllPost');
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you're using functions such as `the_permalink` **that echo their values, but don't return them**, yet you're using them as if they do return values, which they don't.

Aside from a few exceptions, WP functions that start with `the_` don't return data, they echo it, so you have to use functions such as `get_permalink` etc

For example:

```php
$foo = the_title(); // <- this is a mistake, it outputs the title
$bar = get_the_title(); // <- this correct, it returns the title
```

Here, `$foo` has no value, and the posts title was sent to the browser. `$bar` however behaves as expected and returns a post title which is assigned to `$bar`.

Think about it, if `the_title` prints the title of the post, and you write `$title = the_title();` how does it know that you wanted to put it in the variable instead? It doesn't. Computers do exactly what you say, not what you meant. PHP tries to be helpful and will give it an empty value to avoid a fatal error.

---

As an aside, you should never set `posts_per_page` to `-1`, set it to a super high number you never expect to reach, or add pagination, or you run the risk of timeouts and out of memory issues.

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable information. get_the_title() is working for me to display the title name.

Comment: Can I remove posts_per_page from the array? Because I have to show min 15 post on my page.

Comment: You can change it to 15, or 150 even, just don't set it to unlimited. Imagine there was a mistake and 15 million posts got added, maybe a backup was restored multiple times or a plugin update went crazy, or a client changed business plan, the page would never load, it'd never finish. You'll see performance issues with numbers higher than 100/200

Comment: Oh!. Is this true? I haven't notice that.. Thanks for this information. I will set it 15.

Comment: I have one more issue instated of get_permalink. Can you help me to display the slug name? I don't want to show the URL.....

Comment: I'd ask a new question on the site for that. If this answers your original questiion consider marking it as the correct answer

Comment: This is easy for you to display the slug but I am new in WordPress. No Problem I'll research on google first.